# Обеспечить доступ только по устройству

Tags: веб-программирование, ip

Буду рад, если вы поможете в случае, если я неправильно выбрал тему. Вопроса будет два, первый может показаться вам глупым.

1. Есть ссылка: https://raveu.notion.site/Cybe... ad4abda262. Это страница, которую я создал в программе Notion. Допустим, в дальнейшем я хочу предоставлять доступ только определенным людям и исключить возможность делиться ссылкой. Единственный способ, который я вижу - давать доступ исключительно по устройству. Отсюда ряд вопросов: возможно ли это сделать с ссылками подобного рода? Возможно ли это сделать с учётом, что это ссылка будет иметь внутри ещё наполнение и переходы на внутренние страницы?
2. Если первый вариант нереализуем, то как это можно организовать? Через собственный сайт? Есть сторонние приложения?

Answer (score 0):

Для ограничения доступа кого-то куда-то существует аутентификация и авторизация.

Для аутентификации имеются механизмы 1FA и 2FA, а также аппаратные средства вроде смарт-карт.

1FA вас не устраивает, так как теоретический пользователь может добровольно поделиться этим 1FA с кем-то, кто вам не нравится.

**Собственно, начиная с этого момента мы имеем проблему, потому что все эти технические средства работают только при условии, что пользователь не будет добровольно делиться со плохими парнями своими факторами аутентификации.**

Потому что 2FA - это примерно то же самое, но пользователю еще нужно будет пересылать злоумышленнику свой одноразовый пароль при каждом входе.

2FA с физическим токеном - так пользователь даст дружбану токен или свой телефон.

Из всего этого следует, что вы воюете не в ту сторону, и вам нужны на деле средства защиты инофрмации от утечки через компроментацию доверенных акторов.

А для этого нужны не механизмы аутентификации, а всевозможные цифровые водяные знаки, которые позволят вычислить компроментированных акторов и ликвидировать их из процессса информационного обмена.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ! Водяные знаки, защита авторства меня не так интересует, ведь информацию, которую я продаю можно абсолютно спокойно использовать и с водяными знаками. К тому же это чрезвычайно долгая обработка каждого материала с целью нанесения водных знаков и прочего.

Comment: Возможно ли добавить ограничение по IP? Также я рассуждаю на основе примера историй посещения про пользовании ВК, он запоминает устройства, через которые пользователь заходит - возможно ли воспользоваться полученной информацией, чтобы ограничивать доступ к новым устройствам?

Comment: Ну, во-первых вы наверняка не про те водяные знаки думаете:

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A6%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA

Во-вторых, выдумать некую ширму можно всегда, например, раздвавая информацию через приложение, которое будет использовать рекламный идентификатор телефона для привязки.

Фильтрация по IP вам точно не поможет, потому что мобильные сети устроены так, что с одного IP может сидеть целый город.

В четвертых, ничто не помешает Еве просто сфоткать экран телефона (другим телефоном).

Comment: Могли бы вы посоветовать, где можно такую "ширму" изучить или взять для использования? Фотографии с телефона - не так страшно, то количество материала, что будет выложено 
- слишком большое, чтобы беспокоится по этому поводу. Это делать будет просто лень